# Getting a file folder from Open File Dialog

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm a newbie to c++, and I can't figure out how simple get a directory of chose file from open file dialog. I'm trying to use standard functions, in my case it's GetFullPathName.
That's how I'm trying to do:

```
OPENFILENAME ofn;       // common dialog box structure
char szFile[260];       // buffer for file name
HANDLE hf;              // file handle
// Initialize OPENFILENAME
ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
ofn.hwndOwner = hWnd;
ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
// Set lpstrFile[0] to '\0' so that GetOpenFileName does not 
// use the contents of szFile to initialize itself.
ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
//ofn.lpstrFilter = "All\0*.*\0Text\0*.TXT\0";
ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

// Display the Open dialog box. 

if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn) == TRUE)
    hf = CreateFile(ofn.lpstrFile,
    GENERIC_READ,
    0,
    (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES) NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    (HANDLE) NULL);


char buffer[MAX_PATH];
char *buffer2[MAX_PATH];
GetFullPathName(ofn.lpstrFile,
    ofn.nMaxFile,
    buffer,
    buffer2);

//PathRemoveFileSpec(ofn.lpstrFile);
MessageBox(hWnd, buffer, "Tutorial", 0); // and show the path
```

Comment: winapi isn't a great place for someone new to C++ to be dabbling, quite honestly. For example, `GetFullPathName` expects a pointer to a C string with allocated memory it can write to.

Comment: You should probably describe the expected behavior (presumably, a File Open dialog in this case, but always nice to specify), and the actual behavior.  No dialog, but everything else is fine?  Seg-fault?  Dialog, but in the wrong directory?  Dialog appears fine, but doesn't return an answer?

Comment: The recommended dialog for requesting a directory from the user is `SHBrowseForFolder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [`GetOpenFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927.aspx) returns, the chosen file is stored in the buffer you provided via the `lpstrFile` member. This is the full path to the file (e.g. *C:\Path\To\File.txt*).

To get the folder the file is in all you need to do is strip off the last component. You can do this manually by searching the string backwards for the last backslash character, or use one of the utility functions to do it for you:

```
char chFolderPath[MAX_PATH];
StringCchCopy(chFolderPath, MAX_PATH, ofn.lpstrFile);
PathRemoveFileSpec(chFolderPath);
// chFolderPath now contains "C:\Path\To"
```

Note you'll need to [`#include <shlwapi.h>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759844.aspx) and link with `shlwapi.lib` to use the [`PathRemoveFileSpec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773748.aspx) function.

Comment: I'm getting an error: `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PathRemoveFileSpecA@4 referenced in function "long __stdcall WndProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WndProc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z)`

Comment: Add `shlwapi.lib` to your linker inputs.

Comment: @jonatanpotter I already have `#include <shlwapi.h>`, is there any way to not to add? ^^

Comment: What gave you that error? Linker errors look like `LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'xxxx'`. You need to add it to Project / Properties / Linker / Input.

Comment: thank you. could you give me some information about linker inputs, why do I need to specify them in spite of #include?

Comment: `#include` tells the compiler about the function, linker inputs tell the linker how to find the function (or provide the actual code for the function).

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but why should I specify it, while some libraries I don't have to? (such as stdafx.h)

Comment: @user2688153 As an alternative the Microsoft compiler supports [`#pragma comment(lib,"shlwapi.lib")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7.aspx) to specify linker input in source code (several SDK headers do this already). If you have a Java or .NET background this probably seems needlessly complex, as you would simply tell the compiler where the .jar/assembly file is. These modules contain metadata for the compiler to deduce both type and linker information. This is not (yet) supported for C/C++, where you have to manually feed the compiler and linker.